# Need help calculating geographical distance

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, great-circle

I'm setting up a small program to take 2 geographical coordinates from a user and then calculate the distance between them(taking into account the curvature of the earth). So I looked up wikipedia on what the formula is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance).

I basically set up my python function based on that and this is what I came up with:

```
def geocalc(start_lat, start_long, end_lat, end_long):
    start_lat = math.radians(start_lat)
    start_long = math.radians(start_long)
    end_lat = math.radians(end_long)
    end_long = math.radians(end_long)

    d_lat = start_lat - end_lat
    d_long = start_long - end_long

    EARTH_R = 6372.8

    c = math.atan((math.sqrt( (math.cos(end_lat)*d_long)**2 +( (math.cos(start_lat)*math.sin(end_lat)) - (math.sin(start_lat)*math.cos(end_lat)*math.cos(d_long)))**2)) / ((math.sin(start_lat)*math.sin(end_lat)) + (math.cos(start_lat)*math.cos(end_lat)*math.cos(d_long))) )

    return EARTH_R*c
```

The problem is that the results come out really inaccurate. I'm new to python so some help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please give a concrete example (input, expected output, actual output).

Comment: I entered these coordinates (-6.508, 55.071) and (-8.886, 51.622).
The expected output was 414Km. The actual result was 6473Km

Comment: I'd say this is more than inaccurate, this is wrong >.< Inaccurate might be 420km

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got 4 or 5 or 6 problems:

(1) `end_lat = math.radians(end_long)` should be `end_lat = math.radians(end_lat)`

(2) you are missing some stuff as somebody already mentioned, most probably because

(3) your code is illegible (line far too long, redundant parentheses, 17 pointless instances of "math.")

(4) you didn't notice the remark in the Wikipedia article about using `atan2()`

(5) You may have been swapping lat and lon when entering your coordinates

(6) `delta(latitude)` is computed unnecessarily; it doesn't appear in the formula

Putting it all together:

```
from math import radians, sqrt, sin, cos, atan2

def geocalc(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)

    dlon = lon1 - lon2

    EARTH_R = 6372.8

    y = sqrt(
        (cos(lat2) * sin(dlon)) ** 2
        + (cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dlon)) ** 2
        )
    x = sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dlon)
    c = atan2(y, x)
    return EARTH_R * c



>>> geocalc(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40)
2887.2599506071115
>>> geocalc(-6.508, 55.071, -8.886, 51.622)
463.09798886300376
>>> geocalc(55.071, -6.508, 51.622, -8.886)
414.7830891822618
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all those problems. It certainly looks a lot cleaner than what I did and it works!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the geopy module which has a built-in function for distance calculations, scroll down to "Calculating Distances" in the link below:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geopy

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but your answer would be better if you could include some code on how to achieve OP's goal.

Answer (score 4):

This works (print f returns 2887.26 km as per the worked example @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance):

```
import math

def geocalc(start_lat, start_long, end_lat, end_long):

    start_lat = math.radians(start_lat)
    start_long = math.radians(start_long)
    end_lat = math.radians(end_lat)
    end_long = math.radians(end_long)

    d_lat = math.fabs(start_lat - end_lat)
    d_long = math.fabs(start_long - end_long)

    EARTH_R = 6372.8

    y = ((math.sin(start_lat)*math.sin(end_lat)) + (math.cos(start_lat)*math.cos(end_lat)*math.cos(d_long)))

    x = math.sqrt((math.cos(end_lat)*math.sin(d_long))**2 + ( (math.cos(start_lat)*math.sin(end_lat)) - (math.sin(start_lat)*math.cos(end_lat)*math.cos(d_long)))**2)

    c = math.atan(x/y)

    return EARTH_R*c

f = geocalc(36.12, -86.67, 33.94, -118.40)
print f
```

Notice this line in your submission: `end_lat = math.radians(end_long)`

Comment: You don't need `fabs()`, because `cos(-x) == cos(x)`

Comment: -1 This can go go spectacularly wrong because you are using `atan` instead of `atan2`. Examples: going due south from 45 deg lat to -45 deg lat is 10010 km (OK) but from 45.1 deg to -45.1 deg (a slightly longer distance) produces MINUS 9988 km. A trip from north pole to south pole produces ZERO km!

Comment: @JohnMachin regarding the fabs() comment you are correct for this particular implementation but when teaching the concept of deltas the use of absolute values is correct not simple subtraction.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "teaching the concept of deltas". If I'm at `(x1, y1)` and I want to be at `(x2, y2)`, I tell my stepper motors `deltax, deltay = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)`, no `abs()` in sight; what do you do?

Comment: More: (2) In any case the Wikipedia article referred to them as "differences", not "deltas". Where I come from, difference has a sign. (3) Which of the many deltas mentioned in this page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed a math.sin(d_long) towards the beginning, should maybe be this:

```
 c = math.atan((math.sqrt( (math.cos(end_lat)*math.sin(d_long))**2 +( (math.cos(start_lat)*math.sin(end_lat)) - (math.sin(start_lat)*math.cos(end_lat)*math.cos(d_long)))**2)) / ((math.sin(start_lat)*math.sin(end_lat)) + (math.cos(start_lat)*math.cos(end_lat)*math.cos(d_long))) )
```

Comment: You are correct there. However, I am still getting completely wrong answers.